# Name for the set of n-tuples of elements of some set

Tags: combinatorics, notation

Is there a name/notation for the set of n-tuples of elements of some set? Like $S_n$ for permutations, but with replacement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, $S^n = S \times S \times \cdots \times S = \{(s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_n) : s_j \in S \mbox{ for } 1 \le j \le n\}$.

Is that what you mean?

Comment: This is often referred to as a Cartesian product (or, in this case, $n-1$ such products).

Comment: Yes, this was it. I derped hard, thanks for the help.